# Set connection timeout using psql command line interface

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is there a way to set the connection timeout using `psql` cli? How can I set a connection timeout to something low like 3 seconds using the following:

```
PGPASSWORD=passwordhere psql -h 10.0.0.144 -U myuser -c "select 1" -d mydatabase
```

As far as I can tell, `psql` does not support a connection timeout parameter. In the example above `10.0.0.144` is invalid and this command hangs for a long time. I need the command to fail fast if the host is incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `psql` uses `libpq`, I think the environment variable `PGCONNECT_TIMEOUT` might work for setting connect timeout.

You can check the libpq chapter of the official documentation for more details (do not forget to select the version you are using):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Comment: Confirmed: `PGCONNECT_TIMEOUT` works